# yii-user extension gives an invalid alias error

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

i'm new to yii and downloaded this extension

https://github.com/mishamx/yii-user

i've uploaded all the necessary files into the **protected/** folder

but i keep getting this error. what am i missing?

```
 Alias "user.UserModule" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable.

/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dev2/framework/YiiBase.php(322)
```

i edited my **config/main/php** which now looks like this

```
<?php

// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');

// Define a path alias for the Bootstrap extension as it's used internally.
// In this example we assume that you unzipped the extension under protected/extensions.
Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/bootstrap');

// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'my site',
    'theme'=>'bootstrap', // requires you to copy the theme under your themes directory

    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload'=>array('log'),

    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'application.modules.user.models.*',
        'application.modules.user.components.*',
    ),

    'modules'=>array(
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

        'gii'=>array(
            'class' => 'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password' => 'gii', //Enter Your Password Here
            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            'ipFilters' => array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
            'generatorPaths' => array('bootstrap.gii'),
        ),
        'user'=>array(
            # encrypting method (php hash function)
            'hash' => 'md5',

            # send activation email
            'sendActivationMail' => true,

            # allow access for non-activated users
            'loginNotActiv' => false,

            # activate user on registration (only sendActivationMail = false)
            'activeAfterRegister' => false,

            # automatically login from registration
            'autoLogin' => true,

            # registration path
            'registrationUrl' => array('/user/registration'),

            # recovery password path
            'recoveryUrl' => array('/user/recovery'),

            # login form path
            'loginUrl' => array('/user/login'),

            # page after login
            'returnUrl' => array('/user/profile'),

            # page after logout
            'returnLogoutUrl' => array('/user/login'),
        ),

    ),

    // application components
    'components'=>array(
        'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
            'class' => 'WebUser',
        ),

        'bootstrap' => array(
            'class' => 'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
        ),
        // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),

        ),

        /*'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
        ),*/

        // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database

        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DBNAME',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
        ),

        'errorHandler'=>array(
            // use 'site/error' action to display errors
            'errorAction'=>'site/error',
        ),
        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                ),
                // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
                /*
                array(
                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                ),
                */
            ),
        ),
    ),

    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params'=>array(
        // this is used in contact page
        'adminEmail'=>'admin@******.com',
    ),
);
```

?>

and this is my **config/console.php** file

```
<?php

// This is the configuration for yiic console application.
// Any writable CConsoleApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'My Console Application',

    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload'=>array('log'),

    // application components
    'components'=>array(
        // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database
        'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=*****',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
    ),

        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        ),
        'modules'=>array(

            'user'=>array(
                # encrypting method (php hash function)
                'hash' => 'md5',

                # send activation email
                'sendActivationMail' => true,

                # allow access for non-activated users
                'loginNotActiv' => false,

                # activate user on registration (only sendActivationMail = false)
                'activeAfterRegister' => false,

                # automatically login from registration
                'autoLogin' => true,

                # registration path
                'registrationUrl' => array('/user/registration'),

                # recovery password path
                'recoveryUrl' => array('/user/recovery'),

                # login form path
                'loginUrl' => array('/user/login'),

                # page after login
                'returnUrl' => array('/user/profile'),

                # page after logout
                'returnLogoutUrl' => array('/user/login'),
            ),
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure which version of yii-user you are using, but first download the [latest version from here](https://github.com/mishamx/yii-user) and follow the setting changes from that page too.

make sure you unzip all the files into **protected/modules/user** (NOTE: the modules and user folder doesn't exist so you will have to make one)

once done, insert items into zii.widgets.CMenu array (**protected/views/layouts/main.php**)

```
array('url'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->loginUrl, 'label'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->t("Login"), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
array('url'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->registrationUrl, 'label'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->t("Register"), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
array('url'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->profileUrl, 'label'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->t("Profile"), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
array('url'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->logoutUrl, 'label'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->t("Logout").' ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are working with a linux enviroment, it's possible that your files do not have enough previlage to run files under users module directory.

try this to know if the problem is from here

> chmod -R 777 /protected/modules/user/

Comment: you mean `chmod -R 777 /protected/models/user/` ? yeah its already 777 but still doesnt work

Comment: you should unpack user under MODULES, not MODELS!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but I had also same issue after I loaded last version of yiibooster 4.0.1 version my issue solved by changing all "bootstrap" aliases with "booster" in all part of my application.

As example

```
'bootstrap' => array(
        'class' => 'ext.yiibooster.components.Bootstrap',
    ),
```

with

```
 'booster' => [
        'class' => 'ext.yiibooster.components.Booster',
    ],
```

Also don't forget to use filter methods in all actions:

```
 public function filters(){
    return [
        'accessControl',
        'postOnly + delete',
        ['booster.filters.BoosterFilter - delete'],
    ];
}
```